# automating the linking of library to the llc exe

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

Hi Linux noob here,

I wanted to link the LLC.exe with one of the shared libraries , the thing what I do is in order to make the llc -c to work I have to link them like these

> PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/noob/bin"
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/noob/lib"
>
> export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH

If I give these commands it works , Now I want to automate this so I wrote a this in a .sh (bash script ) file and called it in rc.local file but it does-not work, also I tried to put the above lines in the rc.local still it "llc" doesnt work. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

I tried giving

> echo $PATH
>
> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/noob/bin

is the output

But when I give

> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

It gives me nothing. I just want to execute this lines on startup. The huddle is I dont want to edit anything  in /etc/ directory. PLEASE HELP ME !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet shows that you setting the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables.  PATH is used by the shell to binaries, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to find libraries when you execute a program.  None of those commands are linking anything.

`$echo PATH` will try to deference the `echo` variable.  If that $ is your prompt then it will print "PATH" not the value of the PATH variable.

This is how you echo variables:

```
echo $PATH
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```